# Is there a "natural" subsequence of positive integers $k_1 < k_2 < \ldots$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{k_i} = \Theta (\log \log \log n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

The harmonic series partial sums grow like $\log n$, and the sum of inverses of the first $n$ primes grows like $\log \log n$.  Is there an example of a "nautral" subset of the positive integers (say a subset defined by some interesting property,  like being prime for example) such that the sum of inverses of the first $n$ numbers grows like $\log \log \log n$ ?

Comment: You forgot the "inverse" bit in your formula.

Answer (score 2):

$$k_n=1+\left\lfloor n\cdot\log n\cdot\log\log n\right\rfloor$$
*Proof:*
$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log\log\log x=\dfrac1{x\cdot\log x\cdot\log\log x}$.

Comment: I gave this +1 because it is a definite example with an explicit description of the subsequence.  However I'm hoping someone will post an answer that gives an example like "primes that are expressible in the following form..." so that the $\log \log \log n$ growth  says something about the distribution of the numbers that wasn't immediately obvious from the definition.